# Выгружается приложение через ~5 секунд после suspend Windows Runtime(phone) C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, winrt

Для чистого теста вместо своего проекта я взял пример [Background Audio for Windows Phone 8.1 Sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/BackgroundAudio-63bbc319/view/SourceCode#content) с msdn.

Для имитации длительной загрузки (каких-либо данных, да и самого интерфейса), в файле `MainPage.xaml.cs` в методе `MainPage`, я дописал `Task.Delay(5000).Wait();`

Так вот, если запустить приложение (без отладчика) нажать плей и свернуть, то приложение выгружается, если спустя секунд 5-10 его развернуть, будет надпись "возобновление" длительностью 5 секунд. В случае запуска с отладчиком и использования инструментов для управления жизненным циклом, приложение приостанавливается и возобновляется мгновенно.

Случайно заметил, что если убрать из метода инициализации фоновой задачи (плеера) `deferral=taskInstance.GetDeferral();`
ну и его завершение `deferral.Complete();`

то приложение не выгружается, и разворачивается мгновенно, единственный существенный и логичный минус, это приостановка воспроизведения при сворачивании приложения.

Как можно решить данную проблему с "возобновлением"?